Why FileSearch when used under Module is not working : Wix Toolset v5
<Property Id="FILEEXISTS" >
    <DirectorySearch Id="CheckFileDir" Path="[SourceDir]" Depth="0" >
        <FileSearch Id="CheckFile" Name="Test.txt" />
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

wix.exe : error WIX0001: System.InvalidOperationException: The value '' is not a legal identifier and therefore cannot be modularized.
   at WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller.Bind.ModularizeCommand.ModularizedRowFieldValue(Row row, Field field) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller\Bind\ModularizeCommand.cs:line 130
   at WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller.Bind.ModularizeCommand.ModularizeTable(Table table) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller\Bind\ModularizeCommand.cs:line 68
   at WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller.Bind.ModularizeCommand.Execute() in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller\Bind\ModularizeCommand.cs:line 41
   at WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller.Bind.BindDatabaseCommand.Execute() in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller\Bind\BindDatabaseCommand.cs:line 399
   at WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller.MsmBackend.Bind(IBindContext context) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core.WindowsInstaller\MsmBackend.cs:line 27
   at WixToolset.Core.Binder.BackendBind(IBindContext context) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Binder.cs:line 74
   at WixToolset.Core.Binder.Bind(IBindContext context) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Binder.cs:line 40
   at WixToolset.Core.CommandLine.BuildCommand.BindPhase(Intermediate output, IReadOnlyCollection`1 localizations, IReadOnlyCollection`1 filterCultures, String cabCachePath, Int32 cabbingThreadCount, IReadOnlyCollection`1 bindPaths, Dictionary`2 bindVariables, InputsAndOutputs inputsOutputs, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\CommandLine\BuildCommand.cs:line 324
   at WixToolset.Core.CommandLine.BuildCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\CommandLine\BuildCommand.cs:line 152
   at WixToolset.Tools.Program.Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IMessageListener listener, String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\wix\Program.cs:line 103
   at WixToolset.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\wix\wix\src\wix\wix\Program.cs:line 48

I am using the property later in the module to decide what to do or not. Can anyone please help here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As of now, this is still a WiX Bug (see https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/8558). A real solution will be possible only by a fix to that bug.
To get that code compiling, comment out the DirectorySearch block. That will of course not provide the functionality. In order to get the functionality, you will have to either

move this search to a Package or wixlib rather than a merge module (which may be tedious if this is actually shared code)
wait for the underlying WiX bug to be fixed
write a custom action that does the job - this is not really what custom actions are meant for, but may be the only programmatical workaround.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks matthias, would you be able to provide some suggestions on any workaround for github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/8539
